# Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 Netplan and UFW

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall, ufw

Ok, so I want to make a router using Ubuntu Server 18.04 ( already have the hardware and it all works, I have IPfire currently on it). I’ve looked at all the router distros and they seem rather limited in scope.

## Sources

The article:
https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2016/04/the-ars-guide-to-building-a-linux-router-from-scratch/

The firewall guide:
https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/firewall.html

Ubuntu Server now uses netplan. I've looked at the documentation and it’s fairly clear I am not exactly skilled at this usage of the OS. I was hoping maybe someone could help me “translate” the way this article does it (the way I am more familiar) into the more modern implementation.

How would I make a netplan version of this?

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The WAN interface, marked Lan1 on the case
auto p4p1
iface p4p1 inet dhcp

# The LAN interface, marked Lan2 on the case
auto p1p1
iface p1p1 inet static
    address 192.168.99.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Also, I would prefer to use UFW over directly using iptables, as most of the rules in UFW are also what most of the article states.
One key difference from the article is he has this for the NAT section.

## From article

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

# p4p1 is WAN interface, #p1p1 is LAN interface
-A POSTROUTING -o p4p1 -j MASQUERADE

COMMIT
```

## From firewall guide

```
# nat Table rules
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

# Forward traffic from eth1 through eth0.
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

# don’t delete the ‘COMMIT’ line or these nat table rules won’t be processed
COMMIT
```

But, after I figure out those two sections. I should be able to handle the rest. Any help would be great!

Comment: I solved it. With netplan, there isn't any need to set up the WAN and LAN inputs. This is pretty much taken care of during installation.

The firewall rules are pretty much minimal and worked.

Comment: I had some trouble with netplan and bridged interfaces with dnsmasq -dnsmasq wouldn't come up on time. Its a [known issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dnsmasq/+bug/1777094), and not fixed yet. I seem to recall it worked ok with 2 ports only. I'd *strongly* suggest dumping netplan.  I went with firewalld so I'm not much help with your actual question but

Answer (score 5):

*Full Credit goes to: https://www.ascinc.com/blog/linux/how-to-build-a-simple-router-with-ubuntu-server-18-04-1-lts-bionic-beaver/*

I will assume for the following that you just installed Ubuntu 18.04 and have not done anything with it yet.

### 0. Turn on the firewall in order to make sure the routing rules are actually applied

```
sudo ufw enable
```

### 1. Setup The Network Interfaces

First, we need to configure the network interfaces we will be using.
WAN (enp0s7) – this interface will get an IP from the ISP, so we leave it using DHCP.

LAN (enp3s0f0) – we configure the interface with a static IP within the subnet we are going to use for local area network

Just a little note, Ubuntu 18.04 does not use the traditional network configuration file /etc/network/interfaces. It uses NETPLAN. In my case, there is a config file, called 50-cloud-init.yaml inside the /etc/netplan/ folder. In your case, the file may have a different name, just look for the file with .yaml extension inside netplan folder.

Let’s open it with nano:

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
```

Edit it accordingly to your network needs, in my example I configured like this:

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        enp0s7:
            dhcp4: true
        enp3s0f0:
            addresses:
            - 192.168.1.1/24
            dhcp4: false
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 8.8.8.8
                - 8.8.4.4
                search: []
    version: 2
```

To sum up: enp0s7 which is the WAN, gets IP from internet provider’s modem. enp3s0f0 is LAN part of the router. We need it to have a static IP and DNS servers (in my example I used Google’s). Also we didn’t configure any gateway on enp3s0f0.

Save the configuration with following commands:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

### 2. SETTING UP A DHCP SERVER

Next, we want to set up a DHCP server. We really don’t want to configure each client with static IP within the LAN network. For this task, we need to install the following package.

```
sudo apt-get install isc-dhcp-server
```

Next we need to edit /etc/default/dhcpd.conf file. This tells the DHCP server which network interface it should be listening to. In my case it of course enp3s0f0, the LAN interface.

We enter the command:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server
```

And edit accordingly, in my case it is:

```
INTERFACES="enp3s0f0"
```

Next step would be configuring the DHCP server. This is done by editing the file /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

```
sudo nano /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
```

Here is a bunch of different parameters, most of them are commented with # before every line. To keep it shorter, I will write it down only the parameters I used and/or edit them accordingly my needs. If you want, you can delete all the content of this file and just copy/paste the code below. Of course, you change the IPs, GATEWAYS, etc.. according to your own network configuration.

```
option domain-name "whatever.you.want";
option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
ddns-update-style none;
authoritative;
log-facility local7;
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
     range 192.168.1.101 192.168.1.200;
     option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
     option routers 192.168.1.1;
     option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
}
```

Now let’s apply the settings and enable the DHCP server on boot with following commands:

```
sudo systemctl restart isc-dhcp-server
sudo systemctl enable isc-dhcp-server
```

With the following command, we check the status.

```
sudo systemctl status isc-dhcp-server
```

If everything is correctly set up, there must be a line, saying “ACTIVE“. Otherwise, you messed something up within /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf file. It may be missing some semicolon or bracket.

### 3. CONFIGURING FIREWALL

In order to have a functional router, we need to configure the firewall properly. This is done by writing down some iptables rules. In order to preserve the rules if the server is restarted, I created a script to be executed at boot time.

In Ubuntu 18.04 the file /etc/rc.local doesn’t exist anymore. But we can still create it with:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Next, copy/paste the following script. There are comments explaining each iptables rule. You can delete them if you wish, but you must NOT delete #!/bin/bash. Also, change enp0s7 and enp3s0f0 if your network interfaces have some different names.

```
#!/bin/bash

# /etc/rc.local

# Default policy to drop all incoming packets.
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

# Accept incoming packets from localhost and the LAN interface.
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i enp3s0f0 -j ACCEPT

# Accept incoming packets from the WAN if the router initiated the
#  connection.
iptables -A INPUT -i enp0s7 -m conntrack \
--ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Forward LAN packets to the WAN.
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp3s0f0 -o enp0s7 -j ACCEPT

# Forward WAN packets to the LAN if the LAN initiated the connection.
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s7 -o enp3s0f0 -m conntrack \
--ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# NAT traffic going out the WAN interface.
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp0s7 -j MASQUERADE

# rc.local needs to exit with 0
exit 0
```

This script must be executed at boot time, so we need to make the file executable with the following command:

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/rc.local
```

The default settings on UFW firewall mess with our configuration, and in order for our router to work properly (to forward packages from WAN to LAN), you need to enable the following parameter inside /etc/ufw/sysctl.conf file.
We run the command:

```
sudo nano /etc/ufw/sysctl.conf
```

Now we just remove # in front of the following line:

```
net/ipv4/ip_forward=1
```

There we go! We have a working router, just do a sudo reboot command to reboot the server.

Answer (score 2):

As per my comments - I wouldn't use `netplan` here. Its perfectly fine until you try bridging and I couldn't get it to work reliably. IMO its not ready. As of 18.04 switching back to the classic `ifup` network management is the smart thing to do.

I don't use `ufw` in [my own build](https://journeymangeek.com/?p=196) but it can't be that hard to translate them (famous last words).

`firewalld` uses remarkably similar commands for these and they should translate directly to UFW. The commands are literally "classic" firewall commands. They're untested on `ufw`, and might need some tuning from someone who uses `ufw`.

I don't really like how the `ufw` notes gives a range of IPs over an interface (though you might be forced to), but it should translate to something like this. `enp1s0` is my 'external' interface, and br0 is basically all my other interfaces bridged together

For reference, my `firewalld` setup looks like this:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 nat POSTROUTING 0 -o  enp1s0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -i br0 -o  enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
sudo firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -i enp1s0 -o br0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo firewall-cmd --runtime-to-permanent
```

The second last command is *critical*

And that should translate to something like this.

```
#masquerade traffic coming out from enp1s0 
-A POSTROUTING 0 -o  enp1s0 -j MASQUERADE
# Forward and accept any traffic from br0 to enp1s0  
-A FORWARD 0 -i br0 -o  enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
#accept traffic on existing connections
-A FORWARD 0 -i enp1s0 -o br0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

The default `netplan` configuration, as I recall gives *all* the outputs automatic IP addresses.

This is going to be a problem eventually when you run a DHCP server. You want a static IP address on that interface.

If you *must*, a minimal netplan config looks like this - I think it worked before I tried to bridge things.

- enp1s0 is my external interface
- enp1s0 is internal.

I'm not entirely sure why enp2s0 has dhcp enabled - you might be able to remove that stanza. Optional is useful since you might not always have something plugged into the port

```
network:
    ethernets:
        enp1s0:
            addresses: []
            dhcp4: true
        enp2s0:
            addresses: 
                - 192.168.2.1/24
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
    version: 2
```