# Wireguard client and redirect VPN traffic to ETH

Tags: networking, vpn, wireguard

I have for project to create a site to site VPN with wireguard and two Raspberry Pi 4

Site A- UniFi UDM PRO - Raspberry Pi WG server ------ Site B UDM PRO Raspberry Pi WG client.

the Pi have only one NIC but I suppose that's won't be an issue for the server, for the client I bought an additional NIC (over the Pi's HAT).

Can I redirect the VPN connection (full tunnel) so if a client is connecting the the second ethernet port of the Raspberry Pi only received the WG VPN connection (and an IP from site A) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When connecting to a Wireguard server on your Linux machine, a new network interface is brought up, and all traffic is forwarded through it.

Usually, to connect two interfaces together, you would just easily set up a bridge and connect the two interfaces two it.

However, Bridges work on the OSI Layer-2 (forwarding frames, which are directed to destination MAC Addresses), while Wireguard is a Layer-3 protocol (forwarding IP packets with destination IP addresses) ([more info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)).

So you cannot connect an interface that operates on L3 with a bridge. So you have several options:

1. Use a Layer-2 VPN tunnel (like L2TP+IPSec), with the configuration hassle that incurs.
2. Set up the Raspberry Pi as a Socks proxy that tunnels traffic to Wireguard and bridge the full internet connection to the connected device. This would mean traffic *would not* go through the VPN by default, which most likely isn't what you want.
3. **Set up the Raspberry Pi as a gateway router and forward IP packets to the VPN:**

To achieve this, you'd need the following:

- Enable packet forwarding on the client Pi (set `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` and updating it with `sysctl -p`
- Set up the NAT on your client Pi between both interfaces. This would forward packets from your WG subnet (i.e. `10.0.0.0/24` to the new subnet your Raspberry Pi will take care of and you set up in the DHCP Server (i.e `10.10.0.0/24`).
  There are multiple ways to configure this, but in 2022 using Ubuntu, you should give [Netplan](https://netplan.io/) a try, which allows you to configure all these networks with a YAML file intuitively. There is an [example](https://netplan.io/examples/#configuring-source-routing) on Netplan's website achieving exactly this.
- Set up the raspberry pi as a DHCP server (so the IP configuration is automatic and devices with no manual config also have traffic forwarded): set the `option routers yourRaspberryPisWireguardIP;` in `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` and choose a new subnet to assign IP addresses to the clients. [guide](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-dhcp). You should prepare to make `isc-dhcp-server` play nice with `Netplan`. This [askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1110118/834601) does just that.
- Remember using Netplan will probably override your Wg-Quick network setup, but that's no problem. Just [add your WG client configuration](https://netplan.io/reference/#properties-for-device-type-tunnels%3A) on that same Netplan file in the `tunnels:` section.
- You might want to set up a DNS server on the Raspberry Pi that points to your WG server DNS to avoid leaks.

As you might have guessed, with this last approach all clients connected to your raspberry would seem to come from the same client IP (your Raspberry's) due to NAT. You might be able to change this (Wireguard's server config `AllowedIPs` can be set to a range, but I'm not sure how to exactly achieve that.

---

**TLDR:** [Configure the wg client tunnel using Netplan](https://netplan.io/reference/#properties-for-device-type-tunnels%3A). Set up [NAT using Netplan](https://netplan.io/examples/#configuring-source-routing) between the WG Client interface and the secondary ethernet iface you plan to have your clients on. Set up a [DHCP server](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-dhcp) on your pi on a separate subnet for your clients. Essentially, [build your own router](https://askubuntu.com/a/1110118/834601).

Comment: thank a lot for all this detailed informations, this is exactly what I was looking for.